# Amplifier for Philips HTS7201/HTS7202

Tags: amplifier, audio, identification, speakers, plug

I have "inherited" a Philips 2.1 Home Sound System HTS7201/7202.

The official user manual from Philips can be found [here](https://www.download.p4c.philips.com/files/h/hts7202_12/hts7202_12_dfu_aen.pdf).

It consists of two speakers (left/right), each 5 Ω impedance and a subwoofer with 3 Ω impedance and of a DVD player with integrated audio amplifiers.

The DVD player was damaged with small chance for repair, but the three speakers are undamaged and I would like to use them in my living room.

My questions:

1.) Does anyone know the part numer / technical name of those connectors and their counterparts?

[image]

[image]

2.) Can anyone suggest a proper amplifier for those speakers? The best thing would be of course one "amplifier box" that I can attach to a PC (via a stereo jack, or HDMI, etc.) and that in turn can feed all three speakers (data see below).

Also, I am not sure if a 2.1 home entertainment system like this one needs 3 audio channels or if it just uses a stereo signal and feeds the subwoofer with a "mixture" of L/R channels with a LP filter applied.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those speaker connectors are *Mini Easy-Fit Speaker Jacks*, and they are proprietary Philips, so probably not for sale, and they very probably won't connect to anything else.

You can easily cut them off though, and put on connectors of your own choice, as long as you get the polarity right.

As for an amplifier, you need one that can drive 5 Ω speakers with a power rating suitable for the speakers, and that has a subwoofer connection that can drive a 3 Ω speaker.

There aren't many power amplifiers around with a power subwoofer output, but Google will probably find a few.

You could also leave the subwoofer out and just use the other two speakers, and get a simpler and cheaper power amp.

Comment: What is a reasonable power rating for the amplifier(s)? The sattelite have a rating of max. 120W RMS. However, they have a THD of 30% at this rating so that is incredibly much, right? How do i estimate the max. power at which those speakers still sound well? For sure, one would need specifications to tell exactly, but what is an educated guess? max power / 5 so maybe a max. of around 25W for the sattelites and ~40W for the subwoofer?

Comment: It's a maximum; playing music is usually at far lower power levels; the extra power is nice for dynamic bits though. Also, some speakers need more power than others to sound good. There is no way of telling how much power they need to sound good and loud enough without trying, as it is also a matter of taste and listening habits. Philips claim the amplifier used has a total output power of 440W RMS. My high-end amp makes do with 2 x 75W and sounds great with the right speakers. I can't give you a general answer, sorry.

Comment: BTW maybe the amplifier part of the player still works and has external inputs?

Comment: P.S.: I will go with this one: https://www.audiophonics.fr/en/integrated-amplifier/audiophonics-tpa-sw25f-amplifier-21-class-d-tpa3116d2-2x-50w-100w-4-ohm-black-p-12676.html